# Why is bootstrapping important and what are some of the benefits?

Tags: react-bootstrap

I'm curious why bootstrapping is essential to web development and what are some of the benefits? for example, can it help with developing a website for mobile use like aligning things correctly or can it make the process smoother? Can someone explain that and give some examples to where I can understand the importance of the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bootstrap is not essential to web development! It's popular.**

Because it covers HTML, CSS, Javascript-based design in one package. It's a good choice for some projects that need fast development without letting you to make your hands dirty.

Like other stuffs in the market, Bootstrap is not a silver bullet. It has it's advantages and disadvantages too.

> can it help with developing a website for mobile use like aligning things correctly or can it make the process smoother?

As Bootstrap is mobile-first framework, your answer is obviously yes. It has a flexible mobile friendly [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) that makes your work simpler, and prevents you from hard working with @media rules. Whether your clients see your website on mobile, tablet, or desktop.

Excluding grid system, Bootstrap contains many design templates for typography, forms, buttons, navigation and other interface components, that you can use and finish your projects faster. I'm not a fan of Bootstrap, but it's a good choice for small websites, small teams, or personal projects.

[Here](https://webbymonks.com/blog/what-are-the-pros-cons-of-foundation-and-bootstrap/) is a good comparison between its advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Just curious what do you recommend since I'll be reaching methods today.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment well, but if you're looking for a fast start guide it's good to take a look at [Bootstrap cheatsheet](https://hackerthemes.com/bootstrap-cheatsheet/) and some templates [here](https://startbootstrap.com/themes/) and [here](https://bootstrapmade.com).